# joining 2 table data and show it in datagridview

Tags: c#

hi guys I have 2  tables ex : table1 and table2 how can I select specific column from table1 and specific column from table2 then show results in 1 datagridview  next to each others ex: 2 column from table1 and 3 column from table2 then I want to see 5 column in my datagridview there is no any relation between these two table they are access database tables

```
enter code here var con = Program.GetConnection();
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "select USERID,Badgenumber,Name from table1 join table2 ";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt;
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can you write down to me the SQL command if you can please?

Comment: I'm not going to write the code for you, there is a clair example on how to do it in the link above, follow it.